# How to generate multiple sin waves and plot them in python all on the same graph

Tags: python

I am curious about how to generate 5 or any arbitrary number of sin waves and plot them on the same graph.

Here is the code I wrote

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10)

def f(x):
    fun=[]
    for i in range(1,10):
        fun[i]=np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))
        fun.append
        return fun

plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

The error is list assignment index out of range

Comment: first try to write code and come back when you get error message.

Comment: if you have error then use `print()` to see values in variables.

Comment: you should rather use `for` loop to run `plot` many times, and plot every wave separatelly, not to create `fun` with many waves and use one plot. Many `plot()` will draw on one graph

Comment: you have wrong indentations in function and `return` exits function in first loop.

Comment: I've included a working version of your question in my answer (with explanation on where it was wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `for` to run `plot` many times. And `f(x)` should return only one wave.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))


x = np.linspace(1, 10)

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x, f(x))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be easily achieved with `pandas`, by created a dataframe from your x and y and plotting it.
This answers explains how to do this, while also correcting some errors in your code (which I'll go over):

First, you have an indentation error: the `return fun` is indented so it happens inside the `for` loop, so it happens after the first round of the loop. It should be indented one level out.

Second, your code had an index error because `fun` was initialized as an empty list, which cannot be accessed at any index (so it fails at trying to call `f[0]`). From your next line it appears that you wanted to do it with `append`, but since you wanted to work with `numpy` arrays, it's better to start off with an array (like in my example) and assigning to it as you go along.

Fixing those errors, this would be a working version of your question, with the solution using `pandas` (which I consider to be simpler and more readable, but works no better or worse than the other answer)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

x_max = 10
x = np.linspace(1, x_max)

def f(x,m):
    n = len(x)
    fun=np.zeros((n,m))
    for i in range(m):
        fun[:,i] = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))
    return fun

y = f(x,5)
pd.DataFrame(index=x, data=y).plot()
```